# How can I sign an XLAM file using a certificate we purchased?

Tags: excel, vba, code-signing

I need to sign an .XLAM file using a code signing certificate we purchased (I think from GoDaddy). Supposedly the way to do it is to [install the SIP signing extension](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56617) from Microsoft.

I ran regsvr32.exe on both DLLs and vbe7.dll is in the same folder. But when I run signtool.exe I get:

> SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not
>   recognized. SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to
>   sign: setup\AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam

Any ideas what else I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried through the VBA Editor >> Tools >>> Digital Signature?

Comment: @KostasK. Yes - it isn't listed there. The SIP extension is supposed to list it in there, but is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with a Microsoft support engineer on this and we could not solve it.

But I then tried on another computer - with the SIP installed it works fine. So a solution is use another computer.